# HTTP headers with Android and php with Apache

Tags: php, android, apache, http-headers

I have an app that has a web and android components to it and I wish to identify each of them. For this I am explicitly setting the User-Agent in the HTTP headers to something specific to android. But Apache is not passing the User-Agent to me. If I hit the same URL with the browser from the same machine I get a complete list of headers in the php code when I dump $_SERVER array including the HTTP_USER_AGENT. But I get nothing with the android client( except for SCRIPT_NAME and REQUEST_TIME). Does Apache filter stuff out?

I see that if I don't set the headers in the Java code nothing is passed. I use tcpdump and see the following as the User-Agent passed to the server.

```
User-Agent: Android app1.0\r\n
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the code I use to add the User-Agent header in my Android app.

```
HttpPost postObj = null;

httpHost = new HttpHost(MyBaseURL);

postObj = new HttpPost(urlpath);

postObj.setHeader("User-Agent", "Android app1.0");

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpHost, postObj);
```

Thanks,

P

Comment: Are you using HttpClient and HttpPost/HttpGet for your web requests?  How are you adding the headers?  Show a little bit of your code for how you're adding your headers to the request, and we can probably get a more clear idea.

Comment: Apache by itself wouldn't filter, but there are security modules which can clean up headers, mod_security for one.

Comment: @Rich - I have added the code I use to the original question. Barring a stupid misspelling I am pretty sure I am adding the User-Agent to the header as I see it in tcpdump.

Comment: @Marc - I do not have mod_security but I have mod_ssl, mod_python, svn and php.

Comment: Is this all local or are you going through some other server? I know in my company we have apache, but apache is behind a hardware gateway that sucks out all the good header stuff.

Comment: @mezmo - This is a test server I have at home. It just goes through a standard Linksys router. I do not expect it to do any filtering though I have not run tcpdump on the server yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read a little bit about the spec on Wikipedia and the link that wikipedia provides to the actual RFC containing the definition of requirements for UA strings, and there seems to be a requirement that the product and version be separated by a slash.  Check these out:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Format

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-3.7

Maybe Apache is deciding that your string is an invalid User-Agent string and not considering it.  Try changing

```
Android app1.0
```

to

```
Android-app/1.0
```

Comment: Wow! That worked! I had no idea that there is a format specified for the User-Agent. I assumed its a string. Even more puzzling Apache is filtering it out if its not in the correct format. Thanks a lot I would never have figured it out as I was not even suspecting it.